In the Foreigner novel series (C.J. Cherryh, J. Fancher), what constellation is the Atevi homeworld part of?
In the Foreigner novel series (C.J. Cherryh, J. Fancher), what constellation is the Atevi homeworld part of?
Some details are perhaps found in the prequel duology,... but seeing as Kindle ebooks doesn't sell them... I can't determine the original flight path of the Starship Phoenix which suffered a malfunction on route from planet Earth, Sol system.
